# BIOS not fully ACPI compliant - P4VP-MX

Tags: bios, cmos

My BIOS got reverted and I'm freaking out. (I think this was due to me replacing my CMOS). My PC is showing funny symbols instead of normal texts. So I thought I have to reformat and reinstall windows xp: when I am on the process of reinstalling, a stop error occurred which impeded on my progress. See the image below:

[image: Screenshot of error]

How will I be able to fix this?

Comment: *Replacing your CMOS?* A physical chip replacement? A BIOS firmware flash? A battery replacement? A physical jumper/button reset? Could you please be more specific on what you mean by replacing your CMOS?

Comment: Sorry CMOS battery

Answer (score 0):

If you removed your CMOS battery, it's possible that a BIOS setting was set back to factory defaults. These days, many BIOS are pretty good at auto-detecting/configuring hardware. In this case, it would appear that the settings for [ACPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface) got turned on during the reset. For this I would recommend you access your BIOS configuration (the method of this is specific to your motherboard) and turn ACPI off.

Alternatively, you could follow the text on screen that reads:

> ...you can turn off ACPI mode during text mode setup. To do this, simply press the F7 key when you are prompted to install storage drivers. The system will not notify you that the F7 key was pressed - it will silently disable ACPI and allow you to continue your installation.

Either way you do it, i hope this helps.

Comment: ACPI mode is already turned off :(

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates an invalid ACPI table checksum. I would suggest going into your BIOS set and reverting all settings back to their defaults. Then go through every page and change any settings that you need to change.

If that doesn't solve the problem, check for a BIOS upgrade. Unfortunately, even the latest BIOS for this motherboard is around 6 years old. So getting it to work correctly may be something of a challenge. (The relevant standards were finalized in 2004. So they had two years to get it right.)

Comment: I've already done loading the default settings but it seems the same.